# Clingo Printing Duplicated Answers?

Tags: clingo

I'm having trouble interpreting the `clingo v 5.2.2` output below:

[image]

Why did `clingo` print `answer1` twice? I've checked that the two `answer1`s are exactly the same.

I'm using [optimization](https://github.com/ZeningQu/asp-so/blob/750afcb718624abe5b6c8d8f84ecb64c795fd9e7/optimize.lp#L3) in my code. Could that be the problem?

I've set up a [test repo](https://github.com/ZeningQu/asp-so). The above output can be generated by running the following line in the test repo.

```
clingo --opt-mode=OptN examples/swap-shift.lp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I understand now: with the `--opt-mode=OptN` option, `clingo` will try multiple models until it finds all the optimal models, and it will print all the models it has witnessed followed by the optimal models. I think that could explain why `answer1` was printed twice in my original question.

In the output, I think `Models` is the number of total witnesses (including the first optimal model that got printed twice). `Optimal` is the number of optimal models found.

I made my observation by observing the output of [this example](https://github.com/uwdata/draco/blob/master/asp/examples/scatter.lp)

```
clingo --opt-mode=OptN asp/_all.lp asp/examples/scatter.lp
```

See how `Optimization` decreases and the two optimum models are printed in the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While looking for an optimal answer set, clingo prints each answer set that is better than previously found answer sets.
If no better answer set can be found, this means that the optimality of the last answer set has been proved.
If you have use the optN mode, clingo then enumerates all answer sets with that optimal cost. This will again find the first optimal answer set that was found.

I personally do not know how to print only the optimal answer sets and each only one from the command line. It would be possible to implement such a behavior using the Python API.

Answer (score 1):

As per official guide, you can use the flags `--opt-mode=optN --quiet=1` to find and print all optimal solutions.

> To compute all optimal answer sets, we can change clasp’s
> optimization mode using option ‘--opt-mode=optN’. In this mode, clasp
> first prints the tenta- tive answer sets where optimality is not yet
> proven and afterwards prints the optimal answer sets. Note that the
> first optimal answer set is printed twice in this mode. To omit
> tentative answer sets in the output and only print optimal answer
> sets, we can add option ‘--quiet=1’

From the Potassco guide version 2.2.0.